# Puzzle Game index out of range exception

Tags: c#, windows

This exception only occurs when changing game settings from 4 `LengthSides` to 9/16/25. Thanks in advance.

```
int LengthSides = Properties.Settings.Default.NumberOfSquares;
Image image;
PictureBox picBoxWhole = null;
PictureBox[] picBoxes = null;
Image[] images = null;

private void playLevel()
        {
            try
            {
                currentLevel = LengthSides;

                if (picBoxWhole != null)
                {
                    panel1.Controls.Remove(picBoxWhole);
                    picBoxWhole.Dispose();
                    picBoxWhole = null;
                }

                if (picBoxes == null)
                {
                    picBoxes = new PictureBox[currentLevel];
                    images = new Image[currentLevel];
                }

                int numRow = (int)Math.Sqrt(currentLevel);
                int numCol = numRow;
                int unitX = panel1.Width / numRow;
                int unitY = panel1.Height / numCol;
                int[] indice = new int[currentLevel];

                for (int i = 0; i < currentLevel; i++)
                {
                    indice[i] = i;

                    if (picBoxes[i] == null)
                    {
                        picBoxes[i] = new MyPictureBox();
                        //picBoxes[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                        picBoxes[i].Click += OnPuzzleClick;
                        picBoxes[i].MouseHover += PB_MouseHover;
                        picBoxes[i].MouseLeave += PB_MouseLeave;
                        picBoxes[i].Refresh();
                    }

                    picBoxes[i].Width = unitX;
                    picBoxes[i].Height = unitY;

                    ((MyPictureBox)picBoxes[i]).Index = i;

                    createBitmapImage(image, images, i, numRow, numCol, unitX, unitY);

                    picBoxes[i].Location = new Point(unitX * (i % numCol), unitY * (i / numCol));

                    if (!panel1.Controls.Contains(picBoxes[i]))
                    {
                        panel1.Controls.Add(picBoxes[i]);
                    }
                }

                shuffle(ref indice);

                for (int i = 0; i < currentLevel; i++)
                {
                    picBoxes[i].Image = images[indice[i]];
                    ((MyPictureBox)picBoxes[i]).ImageIndex = indice[i];
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

**Error screenshot:**
[image]

**Update:**
I can share this project to test and fix this bug. When changing from bigger value to smaller than it works (for example 25 - 4), otherwise it throws this exception.

```
private void switchImages(MyPictureBox box1, MyPictureBox box2)
        {
            int tmp = box2.ImageIndex;
            box2.Image = images[box1.ImageIndex];
            box2.ImageIndex = box1.ImageIndex;
            box1.Image = images[tmp];
            box1.ImageIndex = tmp;

            if (isSuccessful())
            {
                stopAllTimers();
                firstBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                secondBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                box1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                box2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                Properties.Settings.Default.LevelCompleted = true;
            }
        }
```

**Screen:**
[image]

Comment: Please paste the full exception stack trace

Comment: please indicate on which line you get the error

Comment: Are you initializing your `picBoxes` and `images` arrays when you change `LengthSides`?  because, the second time you call `playLevel` `picBoxes` is not null and it's already initialized. I guess in your code, where you change `LengthSides` you should set `picBoxes` to null

Comment: @Pikoh 

Ok. I will try it and reply.

Comment: @Pikoh

It doesn't work. I get another exception or image is not divided to pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. I initialized all with 0 before `picBoxes = new MyPictureBox[currentLevel];
images = new Image[currentLevel];` initialization and also changed from `PictureBox[]` class to `MyPictureBox[] picBoxes = null;` and now it works.

```
         if (picBoxes != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < picBoxes.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (picBoxes[i].Image != null)
                    {
                        picBoxes[i].Image = null;
                    }

                    picBoxes[i].Index = 0;
                    picBoxes[i].ImageIndex = 0;
                    picBoxes[i].Width = 0;
                    picBoxes[i].Height = 0;
                    picBoxes[i] = null;
                }

                images = null;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `LengthSides` you need to change the size of the arrays `picBoxes` and `images`.

Now you are using the old size

```
      if (picBoxes == null)
        {
            picBoxes = new PictureBox[currentLevel];
            images = new Image[currentLevel];
        }`
```

I hope I understand the question correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the size of the arrays?

Doesn't it changes here: `currentLevel = LengthSides;` ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this if-branch

```
if (picBoxes == null)
{
    picBoxes = new PictureBox[currentLevel];
    images = new Image[currentLevel];
}
```

At the init, `picBoxes` is `null` so that this block is being executed. The variables `picBoxes` and `images` are set with a width, based on the value of `currentLevel` which is then defined by

```
currentLevel = LengthSides;
```

In your question, you have said that the problem occurs when " *changing game settings from 4 LengthSides to 9/16/25* ".

I have figured out at the method's name `playLevel()` that this method is called at each level. So if the size gets updated from `4` to `9`,  then

```
currentLevel = LengthSides; // becomes 9
```

But, you don't do nothing with `picBoxes`. Hence the block in the if-statement below

```
if (picBoxes == null)
{
    picBoxes = new PictureBox[currentLevel];
    images = new Image[currentLevel];
}
```

is never called. So `picBoxes` is still in old, but smaller size: 4. Not 9. Of course this would lead to out of range error if your `currentLevel` is higher. Because you're trying to loop from 0 to 8 (`i < currentLevel`) while the length of `picBoxes` is maximum 4 so far.

Simple solution: re-initialize the `picBoxes` **and** the `images` fields. (Just remove the condition check)

Comment: When I remove the condition or set `picBoxes = null` after `LengthSides` value has been set the `picBoxes` doesn't switches (divides image to pieces).